# Trying to put caret (cross-browser) at the end of line on focus

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, contenteditable

Consider the following `contenteditable` element

```
<div contenteditable>
    Foo bar <span contenteditable="false"></span>x</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/va1uxybk/3/)

Now, the nice thing going on here is that whatever browser you take, the caret is always placed after the `x` if you click somewhere inside.

But, because I don't want the `x` at the end of the line and you remove the `x` the behaviour of where the caret is placed is different (safari and Edge do strange things). So, I figured that when the last line of a `contenteditable` ends with a `span` which is not editable you will have problems, so I did

```
<div contenteditbale>Foo Bar <span con...="false"><span></span></div>
```

Which actually doesn't help at all, same behaviour. It seems that the caret will not show inside an empty span

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So are you saying the caret is going inside the span, or is it a separate element? You could create a [CSS Pseudo Element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) to position the caret where you would like it. Just use:

```
div::after {
    content: url(caret.png);
}
```

Here's an updated [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/va1uxybk/7/)

Comment: In my case, I need to use the native caret, meaning I cannot use a `png`

Comment: Include whatever you'd like in "content". The point is that you can likely use a pseudo element to accomplish your goal, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish. This would place the caret element after the contenteditable div, and should avoid the issue of creating an editable child element inside the div. If placement is an issue, then you can adjust the css to div ::after to place the caret where you need it (in relation to the original div).

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood your answer. Unfortunate if I open it in Safari for example, the caret is not placed after the not editable span?

Comment: So if you want it after the span, you can change "div::after" to "span ::after". If the problem is positioning, you can always adjust positioning inside the pseudo element. For instance, "span::after { content: "caret"; margin-left: 5px}" etc. can you provide your current code?

Comment: if I do that I still get the same behaviour in safari en Edge ( [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va1uxybk/10/). It will not surprise me if this has to be fixed using javascript

Comment: I've created a solution using javascript: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va1uxybk/26/)